# SQL subselect queries with use of the table outside subselect

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to retrieve the count the number of times that a teammate has beat his teammate based on `DRIVERPOSITION`, however i keep getting that `invalid select-list in subselect` i guess this is because i use the `b` and `a` table inside the subselect query?

**Sample Data**

```
RACEID  CONSTRUCTORID  DRIVERID  DRIVERPOSITION
970     4              826       3              
970     4              807       7
960     4              826       4              
960     4              807       7
970     3              820       10              
970     3              810       12
960     3              820       13              
960     3              810       11
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
RACEID  CONSTRUCTORID  DRIVERID  WINS
970     4              826       2              
970     4              807       0
960     3              820       1              
960     3              810       1
```

**What i tried so far**

```
SELECT 
(
SELECT COUNT(
CASE 
WHEN b.DRIVERPOSITION > a.DRIVERPOSITION THEN 1
ELSE 0 END
)
FROM QUALIFYING b 
WHERE RACEYEAR = to_char(NOW(), 'YYYY')
AND a.CONSTRUCTORID = b.CONSTRUCTORID
AND a.RACEID = b.RACEID
AND a.DRIVERID != b.DRIVERID
)
FROM QUALIFYING a
INNER JOIN RACES 
ON a.RACEID = RACES.RACEID
INNER JOIN DRIVERS
ON a.DRIVERID = DRIVERS.DRIVERID
INNER JOIN CONSTRUCTORS
ON a.CONSTRUCTORID = CONSTRUCTORS.CONSTRUCTORID
WHERE RACEYEAR = to_char(NOW(), 'YYYY');
```

Comment: Edit you question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a tag with the database you are using.  You have a high enough reputation that you should know how to ask a good question.

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select raceid, constructorid, driverid,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numwins
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by raceid, constructorid order by driverposition) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) d
group by raceid, constructorid;
```

However, I have no idea how this fits into your query.  Your sample data refers to one table.  Your query has multiple table references.